# Cypress get href attribute

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

I have a test case in which I have a link which opens in a new tab. Since Cypress doesn't support multiple tabs, I want to get the `href` attribute of that link and then open it in the same tab. I'm trying to do it this way, but for some reason it doesn't work.

```
it('Advertise link should refer to Contact page', () => {
    var link = document.querySelector("div.footer-nav > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a").href;
    cy.visit(link);
    cy.title().should('include', 'Text');
});
```

Comment: " it doesn't work" can you be more clear? What specific behavior are you seeing, and what do you want to see?

Comment: Some other things to consider - 1) does `var link` get the correct path 2) have you tested it in a browser 3) does the `visit()` need a `cy.wait()` for the page to settle?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

The code below should do what you're trying to achieve. There is also an entire [recipe with suggestions on how to test links that open in new tabs](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/testing-dom__tab-handling-links/cypress/e2e/tab_handling_anchor_links_spec.cy.js).

```
it('Advertise link should refer to Contact page', () => {
   cy.get('div.footer-nav > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a')
     .should('have.attr', 'href').and('include', 'contact')
     .then((href) => {
       cy.visit(href)
     })
})
```

I would also suggest reading through the Cypress document on the best ways to assign and work with variables: https://on.cypress.io/variables-and-aliases

Comment: _href_ is a JQuery<HTMLElement> so the compiler complains because it is not assignable to a string, but then it works well running the test. How to avoid the warning? 
I'm using Visual Studio Code and cypress 8.3.1

Comment: you can avoid warning by converting JQuery Element to String: cy.visit(String(href))

Answer (score 52):

### Solution 1: `invoke("attr", "href")`

Navigate to the URL specified in the element's href attribute:

```
cy.get(selector)
      .invoke('attr', 'href')
      .then(href => {
        cy.visit(href);
      });
```

Reference: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/invoke.html#Function-with-Arguments

---

### Solution 2: Prevent content from opening in a new tab.

Remove the target attribute from the anchor element, then click on it to navigate to its URL within the same tab:

```
cy.get(selector).invoke('removeAttr', 'target').click()
```

Reference: https://docs.cypress.io/examples/examples/recipes.html#Tab-Handling-and-Links

Comment: This is amazing approach in order to keep testing what happens in the new tab without going to new tab, which is unsupported in cypress. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue:

First - check if href have right value

Second - create another test in which visit that href

Value for href was hard coded in my case.

Comment: Just some side notes: 
-Your selector is "div.footer-nav > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a" too complicated, if there is a simple way to select that value ( maybe check attribute or if href start with something specific )
- The idea of Cypress is E2E so 1 test should be bigger and do more assertion than unit/integration tests

Answer (score 0):

I used something similar in a test:

```
cy.get('a').each(($el) => {
    const herf = $el.attr('href');
    cy.log(herf);

    // then I will do your test:
    cy.visit(link);
    cy.title().should('include', 'Text');

});
```