# Click on ng-if value from cypress

Tags: cypress

I have a parameters tab and I want to click that tab.

[image: Schreenshot of parameters tab]

Below is the HTML for same. Please help I am unable to click on the tab due to `ngIf: activewizmenu != 'parameters'`.

```
<div class="navigation-tab">
    <!-- ngIf: activewizmenu == 'parameters' -->
        <!-- ngIf: activewizmenu != 'parameters' -->
            <div ng-if="activewizmenu != 'parameters'" class="ng-scope">
                <!-- ngIf: hasCreatedTask() -->
                    <div ng-if="hasCreatedTask()" class="ng-scope" style="">
                        <a ui-sref=".parameters" href="#/game/wizard/G_1544166059776_U/edit">
                            <div class="tab">
                                <img src="images/gamification/panel_icons/icone_mw_gametab_0018_Oggetto-vettoriale-avanzato-copia-9.679f1df3.png" alt="parameters">
                                <div class="heading ng-binding">PARAMETERS</div>
                                <span class="color-purple ng-binding">Set parameters</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                <!-- end ngIf: hasCreatedTask() -->
            <!-- ngIf: !hasCreatedTask() -->
        </div>
    <!-- end ngIf: activewizmenu != 'parameters' -->
</div>
```

Comment: I need more information. Can you show us the cypress code? You are using angular JS it looks like. I am confused, is your element not showing in the DOM due to the condition. If your element is truly on the screen I should be able to help you. Is this condition activewizmenu != 'parameters' true when you run your test

Answer (score 1):

In AngularJS `ngIf` will completely remove the element and it's children from the DOM when the expression is false, so using `cy.get().click({force: true})` is likely to be insufficient.

In this DOM, `<a ui-sref=".parameters" href="#/game/wizard/G_1544166059776_U/edit">` is the clickable element.

To select it you will need a selector which is specific to this tab, since there are other tabs on the page also with `href` and there are no distinguishing classes or ids. (AngualrJS adds class `ng-scope` to lots of elements).

See this page [Attribute Contains Prefix Selector [name|=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/) for syntax of selecting by an attribute and it's value.

I would try the following

```js
cy.get("a[href|='#/game/wizard/G_1544166059776_U/edit']")
  .should('be.visible')
  .click()
```

This will wait 5 seconds for the clickable element to appear. If it doesn't do so, it will fail with a message like ***timeout out expecting a[href] to be visible***.

If it does fail (for instance if `activewizmenu != 'parameters'` never becomes true), then you can still navigate to the target of the href as per this question [Cypress get href attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48348354/cypress-get-href-attribute),

```
cy.visit('#/game/wizard/G_1544166059776_U/edit')
```

Comment: I am able to do it by changing the attribute value:
cy.get('.navigation-tab > .ng-scope > a > .tab')
    .invoke('attr','ng-if','activewizmenu = parameters')
  cy.contains('PARAMETERS').should('not.be.visible')
       .click({force: true})

Comment: Good work. If you post it as an answer, I'll vote for it.

Answer (score 1):

By changing the attribute value. It worked.

```
cy.get ('.navigation-tab > .ng-scope > a > .tab')
.invoke('attr','ng-if','activewizmenu = parameters')
cy.contains ('PARAMETERS').should('not.be.visible')
.click({force: true})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.click()` with the option `{ force: true }`.

This will force the click and all subsequent events to fire even if the element isn't considered 'actionable'.

Example:

```
cy.get(##your element identifier##).click({ force: true })
```

Comment: If i am writing this then 5 elements will be found. I am getting error "CypressError: cy.click() can only be called on a single element. Your subject contained 5 elements. Pass { multiple: true } if you want to serially click each element."

Comment: I add `.navigation-tab` to my answer just as an example. You should pass the right element you want to click to the `get()` function. The important here is to add `{ force: true }` to the click handler.

Comment: Yes,While trying that i am not getting error but still it is not clickable.

Comment: I am confused. Are you trying to click an element that should NOT be clicked in the current state of your app?