# Cypress - attribute containing text and end of string

Tags: javascript, cypress

Let's assume I have such html:

```
<div class="my_class" id="first_case">
  <a href="/foo/bar/123"></a>
</div>

<div class="my_class" id="second_case">
  <a href="/foo/bar/1234567"></a>
</div>
```

I want to make assertion that there is an item with href, which ends with '/123'.

```
const test_id = '123'

cy.get('.my_class').find('a').should("have.attr", "href").and("contain", '/' + test_id);
```

It works, however I don't know how to make sure that the assertion is true only for href with exact ending ('/123', as shown in #first_case in first code snippet) and that it is false for other strings starting with such number, for example ('/1234567', as shown in #second_case in first code snippet).

In other words, the assertion should be true for #first_case, but false for #second_case.

I tried using end of string symbol or making new RegExp object, however couldn't make it work.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vanilla JS, you can try with `querySelector()` and *attribute ends with selector* (`[name$="value"`). Please note, you forgot to close the `a` element.

```js
const test_id = '123'
var el = document.querySelector(`[href$="${test_id}"]`);
console.log(el);
```

```html
<div class="my_class" id="first_case">
  <a href="/foo/bar/123"></a>
</div>

<div class="my_class" id="second_case">
  <a href="/foo/bar/1234567"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: cy.get(\`[href$="${test_id}"]\`)
 works as I wanted. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 9):

`.should()` will yield you the href so you can use it in a `.then()` block however you like (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48451157/2883129), so you can use `.endsWith()`:

```
const test_id = '123'

cy.get('.my_class')
  .find('a')
  .should("have.attr", "href")
  .then(href => {
    expect(href.endsWith(test_id)).to.be.true;
  });
```

Or to make it a bit more readable and a failure message to be clearer, you could use https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-string/:

```
const test_id = '123'

cy.get('.my_class')
  .find('a')
  .should("have.attr", "href")
  .then(href => {
    expect(href).to.endWith(test_id);
  });
```

Answer (score 7):

I think there's even easier way to do this. You can use a single `cy.get()` and single `should()` because Cypress selectors should behave the same way as jQuery selectors do.

```
cy.get('.my_class a[href$="/123"]').should('have.length', 1);
```

`$=` will match only attributes that end with `/123`.